# How to use WeakChangeListener with JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, weak-references, changelistener

I wrote my TableCell implementation based on TableCell. I'm using ChangeListener, but it is not **garbage collected**. How to use WeakChangeListener in this case. Please see my code. How to switch it to WeakChangeListener.

```
    changeListener = new ChangeListener<Object[]>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object[]> observable, Object[] oldValue, Object[] newValue) {
            if (newValue != null && oldValue != null) {
                if (oldValue[21].equals(newValue[21])) {
                    if (newValue[updateBasedValues] != null) {
                        if (!newValue[updateBasedValues].equals(oldValue[updateBasedValues])) {
                            justUpdated = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };        
    itemProperty().addListener(changeListener);
```

Comment: The public facing API of these two objects appears to be almost identical.  Are you sure a simple Find and Replace won't suffice?

Comment: What do You mean by find and replace, I tried to remove listener in finalize function, it dosen't work for me? :/

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep a reference to the weak listener so that it is not garbage collected too soon.
Read this very good discussion on the oracle forum : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2396063

I've written an adapter class "WeakAdapter" that you can use or extend.
Example on how to use this class:
Instead of writing

```
myBooleanProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean> () {...});
```

use:

```
weak = new WeakAdapter();
weak.addChangeListener(myBooleanProperty, new ChangeListener<Boolean> (){});
```

Here is the code of class WeakAdapter:

```
public class WeakAdapter {

    ArrayList<Object> listenerRefs = new ArrayList<>();

    public WeakAdapter() {
    }

    public void dipose() {
        listenerRefs.clear();
    }

    public final <T> void remove(ChangeListener<T> listener) {
        listenerRefs.remove(listener);
    }

    public final <T> void addChangeListener(final ObservableValue observable, ChangeListener<T> listener) {
        listenerRefs.add(listener);
        observable.addListener(new WeakChangeListener<>(listener));
    }

    public final <T> WeakListChangeListener<T> addListChangeListener(ListChangeListener<T> listener) {
        listenerRefs.add(listener);
        return new WeakListChangeListener<>(listener);
    }

    public void addInvalidationListener(final Observable listened, InvalidationListener listener) {
        listenerRefs.add(listener);
        listened.addListener(new WeakInvalidationListener(listener));
    }

    public final void stringBind(final StringProperty propertyToUpdate, final StringExpression expressionToListen) {
        ChangeListener<String> listener = new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String name) {
                propertyToUpdate.set(name);
            }
        };
        listenerRefs.add(listener);
        expressionToListen.addListener(new WeakChangeListener<>(listener));
        listener.changed(null, null, expressionToListen.get());
    }

    public final void booleanBind(final BooleanProperty propertyToUpdate, final BooleanExpression expressionToListen) {
        ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean name) {
                propertyToUpdate.set(name);
            }
        };
        listenerRefs.add(listener);
        expressionToListen.addListener(new WeakChangeListener<>(listener));
        propertyToUpdate.set(expressionToListen.get());
    }
}
```